# which is better, "We hope our close partnership can continue or can be continued well into the future"?

Tags: active-voice

which is better, "We hope our close partnership can continue well into the future" or "We hope our close partnership can be continued well into the future"?

Comment: We hope our close partnership *will* continue...

Comment: 'Continue' is used as a transitive verb, when a fair range of DO's such as partnership are available, as is the passive. This licenses the second variant grammatically. But 'continue' also has a middle usage. The partnership can continue. So the first variant is also grammatical.  Which is preferable is probably POB, but I'd choose a different phrasing as per some ('incorrect' as they give unsolicited workarounds) answers.

Answer (score 3):

As @Lamar Latrell comments, it may be best to use ***will* continue**.

Of the two options given in the question, though:

> "We hope our close partnership can continue well into the future"

is better. I say *better*, although both options make good sense, and are fine grammatically. It's just a matter of the nuanced implications of the sentences.

Using the passive voice, "can be continued", suggests that there is some doubt about the possibility of its continuing, *and* that there is effort involved in making it continue (that one or more of the parties in the partnership is the implied agent who makes it continue).

"***can continue***" is more suggestive that the partnership will continue naturally, as a matter of course (although there is still a chance that it won't).

So the most friendly, positive statement is to hope that it ***will*** continue.

Conversely, if you ***do*** in fact want to express doubt about the partnership, like if the person you're writing to has been breaking the terms of a deal, it may still be better to use the active voice and make your concern explicit: the passive form can [sound passive-aggressive](https://www.prnewswire.com/blog/grammar-hammer-passive-aggressive-9107.html). Something like:

> We hope you will work more closely with us in future, to continue our partnership...